# How to put content between Drawer.Screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer

I created a drawer with screens but wanted to add text or a View with text inside it in the middle of the DrawerItemList so I could categorize them. I used in the Drawer.Navigator the drawerContent option and used a custom function and called it. As seen in this image [Picture of the drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoYKg.jpg) I wanted for example to put a text between *'Análises Rejeitadas'* and *'Gerir Reagentes'* but i've searched and don't know how to do that, any help would be great!

Here is my code:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const CustomDrawerContent=(props) =>{
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={styles.userArea}>
          <Image style={styles.pfp} source={{ uri: auth.currentUser.photoURL }}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.name}>José Freitas</Text>
          <Text>{auth.currentUser.email}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.line}/>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
   return (
    
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='TabNavigator' drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}> 
        <Drawer.Screen name='Início' component={TabNavigator}/>[enter image description here][1]
        <Drawer.Screen name="Lista de Espera" component={PermissionsStackScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Comunidade" component={CommunityStackScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Análises em Espera' component={AwaitingStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Confirmar Análises' component={VerifyStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Análises Rejeitadas' component={RejectedStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Gerir Reagentes' component={ReagentStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Gerir Equipamentos' component={EquipmentStackScreen}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
  
}

export default DrawerNavigator
```